# LP python line switching in production planning

Tags: python, optimization, solver, pulp

I am trying to create a script to optimize production using linear programming.
There are 2 lines that have overlapping products:
Line 1 can produce: a,b,c in a volume of 10 tons per day.
Line 2 can produce: a,b,d in the amount of 8 tons per day.

Usually each line works 24 hours a day.

Switching the line between the type of product produced takes 2 hours. Accordingly, if the last day 1 line produced a product, and today the solver believes that it is necessary to produce 10 hours of product a and the rest of the time to produce a new product b, then the time limit for the day will be 22 hours.

It is desirable to switch the line no more than once every 3 days.

The input we get is the data:

- the required volume of each product each day to sell
  Example: day 1 requires 5 tons of product a, 6 tons of product d, day 2 requires 8 tons of product c, 2 tons of product a.
- The initial stock balance at the beginning of day 1 is 3 tons of product a, 2 tons of product b, and 3 tons of product c.

It is necessary to get data on the output of which line at what time what product is produced each day during the month in order to maximize the production of the product and take into account the requirements for shipments for sale.

I can not understand how to take into account the possible switching of the line between products and the time cost of 2 hours for this switching.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the details of the model (e.g. discrete-time vs continuous-time etc). This cannot be answered without much more detailed information. How to model changeovers is well known, but explaining this requires quite some text and math and graphics, not really suited for this forum. You may want to do a literature search to see what others have done in this area. Note that no existing published model will exactly do what you want, but it should give you some ideas.

Comment: The model is calculated for the number of days for which there is a sales plan. The calculation is made on request, without continuity. I would be glad if you could share a list of literature on this topic. Thank you!